# Setting a one-click filter to see questions that interest me

Tags: feature-request, support

Is there a general way to set up a filter to see the questions I am interested in - `[tag1] + [tag2] + newest`? I'd like to be able to set up two-three filters like this and be able to access them with one click (say, each filter has its own button on my default page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low tech solution: use your browser's bookmarks.

```
http://site/questions/tagged/tag1+tag2?sort=newest
```

For example:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support+feature-request?sort=newest

Comment: By "and" I meant "display tag1 AND tag2", so actually it's OR. But I figured out how to do that - tag1+or+tag2. Thanks!

Comment: @Dennis, can you see this?